# How can I add numbers to a excel cell?

Tags: excel, function, numbers

I have a list of 100 names in column A. For example John, Jacob, James.

I would like to add the numbers 1-99999 to each cell in column A.

I have the list of numbers, how can I add them to each cell to output like this ? 
John1
John2
John3 ...
Jacob1
Jacob2
Jacob3

Comment: If I read your question literally, you want: `John1`, `John2`, ..., `John99999`, `Jacob1`, `Jacob2`, ..., `Jacob99999`, ..., `James1`, `James2`, ..., `James99999`, ... ? What cells do you want to put them in?

Answer (score 0):

If you place the following formula in Cell B1 and copy down for about 1 million rows, you should get the answer you require:

```
=INDEX(A:A, INT((ROW() - 1) / 99999) + 1) & (MOD(ROW() - 1, 99999) + 1)
```

Comment: How can I do with without coping down (sometimes I have 200-400) ?

Comment: After a recalculation, I realise I'm out by a factor of 10. You will not be able to do this as the maximum row count in an Excel spreadsheet is 1048576 (2^20).

Comment: @user16323 To do it without a formula and copying down/across, you will need to create a macro.

Comment: I'm familiar with macros but what code could execute this formula ?

Comment: @user16323 In general, I wouldn't use the formula in the macro. I'd just generate the expected values by looping over the values in column A and outputting the concatentation results to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on copying down as an answer as I don't have enough reputation

if you place the formula provided by Phylogenesis in to the first cell in the column next to the column with your data the move your mouse to the bottom right hand corner of the highlighted cell the cursor will change in to a cross. Double click the mouse and this will automatically add the formula to all the appropriate cells - assuming there are no blanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub NumberNames()
    Dim jacob As Long, john As Long, james As Long
    Dim i As Long
    jacob = 1
    james = 1
    john = 1
    For i = 1 To 100
        With Cells(i, 1)
            v = .Value
            If v = "John" Then
                .Value = .Value & john
                john = john + 1
            End If
            If v = "Jacob" Then
                .Value = .Value & jacob
                jacob = jacob + 1
            End If
            If v = "James" Then
                .Value = .Value & james
                james = james + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

if your data starts out like:

```
James
Jacob
John
James
John
John
James
John
James
John
Jacob
John
James
James
John
John
James
John
James
James
```

it will end up like:

```
James1
Jacob1
John1
James2
John2
John3
James3
John4
James4
John5
Jacob2
John6
James5
James6
John7
John8
James7
John9
James8
James9
```

Comment: Not usable for 200 users.

Comment: Your post indicated **3** names and **100** entries in column A..............are there more???